# $(a*b)'= a' * b'$ if and only if $a*b = b*a$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group and $a, b \in G$. Show that $(a*b)' = a' * b'$ if and only if $a*b = b*a$.

While this is simple to see by intuition, I am having a hard time expressing this formally. It seems as if I want to show that $(a*b)' = a' * b'$ strictly implies $a*b = b*a$, but I'm not sure how much I am allowed to tweak with the equations, and every time I've tried to solve this, I've caught myself in assuming $a*b = b*a$, which naturally results in a foul proof.

Comment: Does $a'$ mean the inverse of $a$ here (usually $a^{-1}$)?

Comment: Yes. Our book uses $a'$ exclusively. (A first course in abstract algebra, Fraleigh.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Remember that $(a*b)' = b' * a'$ is an identity that always holds.

Comment: I need you to elaborate on this. While $(a*b)' = a' * b'$ is given in the task, how can you assume $(a*b)' = b' * a' $ without further explanation?

Comment: There is no assumption here. $(a*b)' = b' * a'$ is an identity that holds for all $a$ and $b$ in any group. If you want a proof, try multiplying out $(a*b)*(b' * a')$and $(b' * a')*(a*b)$.

Comment: Of course. First week of algebra, all these new notations make me dizzy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by $a'$ you mean $a^{-1}$ :

Suppose $(ab)=(ba)$. Then we know $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$. But $ab=ba$ implies that $(ab)^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$.

Conversely assume that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$. Then $ab=ba$

Answer (score 0):

From your equation
$$
(a * b) = (a' *b')' = b'' * a'' = b * a$$